# Overlaying boxplots on the relative bin of a histogram

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Taking the dataset '*tip*' as an example

| total_bill | tip | smoker | day | time | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16.99 | 1.01 | No | Sun | Dinner | 2 |
| 10.34 | 1.66 | No | Sun | Dinner | 3 |
| 21.01 | 3.50 | No | Sun | Dinner | 3 |
| 23.68 | 3.31 | No | Sun | Dinner | 2 |
| 24.59 | 3.61 | No | Sun | Dinner | 4 |

what I'm trying to do is represent the distribution of the variable '*total_bill*' and relate each of its bins to the distribution of the variable '*tip*' linked to it. In this example, this graph is meant to answer the question: "What is the distribution of tips left by customers as a function of the bill they paid?"

I have more or less achieved the graph I wanted to obtain (but there is a problem. At the end I explain what it is).

 And the procedure I adopted is this:

1. Dividing '*total_bill*' into bins.

   ```
   tips['bins_total_bill'] = pd.cut(tips.total_bill, 10)
   tips.head()
   ```

   | total_bill | tip | smoker | day | time | size | bins_total_bill |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 16.99 | 1.01 | No | Sun | Dinner | 2 | (12.618, 17.392] |
   | 10.34 | 1.66 | No | Sun | Dinner | 3 | (7.844, 12.618] |
   | 21.01 | 3.50 | No | Sun | Dinner | 3 | (17.392, 22.166] |
   | 23.68 | 3.31 | No | Sun | Dinner | 2 | (22.166, 26.94] |
   | 24.59 | 3.61 | No | Sun | Dinner | 4 | (22.166, 26.94] |
2. Creation of a pd.Series with: 
   Index: pd.interval of total_cost bins 
   Values: n° of occurrences

   ```
   s = tips['bins_total_bill'].value_counts(sort=False)
   s
   ```

> ```
> (3.022, 7.844]       7
> (7.844, 12.618]     42
> (12.618, 17.392]    68
> (17.392, 22.166]    51
> (22.166, 26.94]     31
> (26.94, 31.714]     19
> (31.714, 36.488]    12
> (36.488, 41.262]     7
> (41.262, 46.036]     3
> (46.036, 50.81]      4
> Name: bins_total_bill, dtype: int64
> ```

3. Combine barplot and poxplot together

   ```
   fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(dpi=200)
   ax2 = ax1.twinx()

   sns.barplot(ax=ax1, x = s.index, y = s.values)
   sns.boxplot(ax=ax2, x='bins_total_bill', y='tip', data=tips)
   sns.stripplot(ax=ax2, x='bins_total_bill', y='tip', data=tips, size=5, color="yellow", edgecolor='red', linewidth=0.3)

   #Title and axis labels
   ax1.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
   ax1.set_ylabel('Number of bills')
   ax2.set_ylabel('Tips [$]')
   ax1.set_xlabel("Mid value of total_bill bins [$]")
   ax1.set_title("Tips ~ Total_bill distribution")

   #Reference lines average(tip) + add yticks + Legend
   avg_tip = np.mean(tips.tip)
   ax2.axhline(y=avg_tip, color='red', linestyle="--", label="avg tip")
   ax2.set_yticks(list(ax2.get_yticks() + avg_tip))
   ax2.legend(loc='best')

   #Set labels axis x
   ax1.set_xticklabels(list(map(lambda s: round(s.mid,2), s.index)))
   ```

   [image: barplot and poxplot together]

It has to be said that this graph has a problem! As the x-axis is categorical, I cannot, for example, add a vertical line at the mean value of 'total_bill'.

How can I fix this to get the correct result?
I also wonder if there is a correct and more streamlined approach than the one I have adopted.

Comment: The x-axis isn't linear, so even if you place the vertical line somewhere it won't tell you much (what would mean, if it would be somewhere between 15 and 19.78 if the scale) - maybe highlight the bin, that has the mean in it?

Comment: I mean, it is doable - you should take the relative position of neighbouring x-ticks, and then, based on this, calculate the relative position of the mean on axis and draw it with https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html .
But it won't help much in understanding the data.

Comment: @DanielWlazło - I fully agree with what you say! For the purposes of understanding the data, it would have been more than sufficient to highlight the bin.
The problem I mentioned was not in understanding the data but in becoming familiar with the visualisation libraries. Thank you very much for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

I thought of this method, which is more compact than the previous one (it can probably be done better) and overcomes the problem of scaling on the x-axis.

1. I split '*total_bill*' into bins and add the column to Df

   ```
   tips['bins_total_bill'] = pd.cut(tips.total_bill, 10)
   ```
2. Group column '*tip*' by previously created bins

   ```
   obj_gby_tips = tips.groupby('bins_total_bill')['tip']
   gby_tip = dict(list(obj_gby_tips))
   ```
3. Create dictionary with:

    keys: midpoint of each bins interval

    values: gby tips for each interval

   ```
   mid_total_bill_bins = list(map(lambda bins: bins.mid, list(gby_tip.keys())))
   gby_tips = gby_tip.values()

   tip_gby_total_bill_bins = dict(zip(mid_total_bill_bins, gby_tips))
   ```
4. Create chart by passing to each rectangle of the boxplot the
   centroid of each respective bins

   ```
   fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(dpi=200)
   ax2 = ax1.twinx()

   bp_values = list(tip_gby_total_bill_bins.values())
   bp_pos = list(tip_gby_total_bill_bins.keys())

   l1 = sns.histplot(tips.total_bill, bins=10, ax=ax1)
   l2 = ax2.boxplot(bp_values, positions=bp_pos, manage_ticks=False, patch_artist=True, widths=2)

   #Average tips as hline
   avg_tip = np.mean(tips.tip)
   ax2.axhline(y=avg_tip, color='red', linestyle="--", label="avg tip")
   ax2.set_yticks(list(ax2.get_yticks() + avg_tip)) #add value of avg(tip) to y-axis

   #Average total_bill as vline
   avg_total_bill=np.mean(tips.total_bill)
   ax1.axvline(x=avg_total_bill, color='orange', linestyle="--", label="avg tot_bill")
   ```

then the result.

[image: Tips ~ Total_bill distribution]